# Why do my webpage images appear sideways in my HTML but correct when in full screen?

Tags: html, iphone, image

If you look at this page, you will see that the right two images are sideways:

http://www.disneypinplace.com/beta/pin.php?id=PD78685

But when you click on them, they appear correctly in full screen view, vertically. I can't see anything wrong in my HTML img code that could cause this.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? These photos were taken with an iPhone 5 by the way.

Comment: Don't render massive images and scale them down :( It's really slow...

Comment: Nick - My plan is to run them through an image-processor to shrink them on upload... but I want to figure out this issue first. This site isn't live to the public yet.

Comment: Well the 2nd and 3rd images are landscape, and the first one is portrait..

Comment: Original image also appears sideways

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a particular problem with how the iPhone exports images. Seem this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971491/captured-photo-automatically-rotated-during-upload-in-ios-6-0-or-iphone) for a similar situation.

Computers/browsers and iPhone software interpret the camera metadata (details about image, including portrait/landscape) differently thus causing the difference in rendering.

I was able to download the far right image in Pixelmator/Photoshop and save it as a jpg again, making sure it was portrait. This made it so the browser properly rendered the image and did not rotate it 90 degrees.

Comment: incidentally, I just discovered that you can also just open the image in Preview (if you're on a Mac) and hit Save...

Answer (score 0):

Were these pictures taken sideways, by any chance? Have you tried editing and "exporting for web" from Photoshop, for example?

Maybe the problem is on the image EXIF (as in you only see the image correctly because the browser reads the EXIF info and rotate it on screen). Exporting it will most likely remove that info from the image file and it might make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

I spent an hour with this that I'll never get back. :)

**The Problem**

I took the picture on my Samsung GALAXY Tab PRO 8.4. It rendered SIDEWAYS in an Android Emulator as well as in FireFox 42.0.

**The Fix**

I edited the picture in IrfanView.

I went to Properties_Settings -> JPG_PCD_GIF ->
UNCHECK "Auto-rotate Image according to EXIF info (if available)"

It now renders OK in FireFox. I haven't checked the emulator yet.